# Changing select border when it is expanded

Tags: html, css

I am trying to change the border of a select item but only when it is expanded and showing the options
any idea how to do it???

Comment: Share the styles which you've tried first

Comment: Give detail explanation from that everyone can get knowledge

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a simple example;

in HTML,

```
<select>
    <option>option 1</option>
    <option>option 2</option>
</select>
```

in CSS,

```
select { 
    border-color: red;
    border-width: 5px; 
}
select:focus {
    border-color: blue;
}
```

this will change the border-color from red to blue once the user is using the select box.

**edit1 :**
Apparently, when the user has selected an option, the border stays blue until he/she has clicked on an other element outside the select box. A small fix is to use the hover selector. But it will change the color too when the user is hovering the select element, even if the option window is not being displayed.

```
select:hover {
    border-color: blue;
}
```

Feel free to see which one is good for you.

Comment: I have tried it already but when the select (dropdown) is being expanded the border is alwase black no matter what I do

Comment: i have put a test sample on [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tqkYN/) and it works as expected.

Comment: Thanks for the fast response, I need to change the border of the box that is being opened when you click on the select

Comment: Ah the dropdown list ? Well, i'm sorry, but so far, there is no CSS styling available for it. But you can style it by using javascript/jQuery. Please see [this tutorial](http://tympanus.net/codrops/2012/10/04/custom-drop-down-list-styling/) with examples or this [JQTransform](http://www.dfc-e.com/metiers/multimedia/opensource/jqtransform/) plugin.

Answer (score 1):

Ask your question in detailed manner.

To edit any of the widget in html like textbox, textfield, button.., You have to include style tag. Study Style tag [here](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_style.asp)